# Photo safety on my website

Tags: passwords, photos

Hi I created a website from scratch using HTML and style sheets by following a "How to...." book so I am at a very basic level of knowledge.

My question is I have photos on my site wonder how safe they are. Can I make them safe? Can anyone copy them? Would a password to access the site help?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks
Wendy

Comment: A lot of answerers have interpreted the question as 'how can I copy protect my photos'. I think the real question is 'how can I restrict access to my photos'?

Answer (score 6):

Anyone who can see your pictures can copy them.

Comment: So if I had a password to access my site then only people with the password could see my photo`s right?

Comment: If you do it correctly (and it can't be circumvented) - yes. But these people will be able to save the photos too.

Answer (score 3):

is it *really* worth the hassle to "protect" the images though?

are they examples of your photographic portfolio? if so, they will be in a low enough resolution online to where they are obviously inferior to the originals.

are they just pictures of you and your family or friends? if so, you might just be paranoid.

like what was alluded to earlier, the moment someone even *looks* at your picture, buy the very nature of the internet, the image has been copied to their computer for viewing.

why fight it?

Comment: Very true Henrikpp! Maybe I am being paranoid. It will be just friends and family pics and I suppose they already put them on the other sites out there and if they didn`t want to put them on then it`s up to them. Note to self...be less paranoid!!

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is include some form of visual distortion in the image. Overlay them with semi-transparent text of your name or something like google do with google maps. This will at least make it harder for anyone to re-use them.

(It's not 100% perfect though, I'm sure there are techniques for removing overlays)

Alternatively, only supply lo-res versions for free. Make people pay for them if they want high-res copies.

Answer (score 1):

If you reference your photos via

```
<img src="...."/>
```

the browser makes a request for those photos *just as if you typed that address in the browser window*. So any reference like the above is not going to be safe.

Users can also select a photo and (depending on your browser) select the `Save As` option.

Finally those photos are going to end up in the browser cache, and possibly on a disk.

Some sites will disable the right-click on the document images, but that's not a good fix. If you're worried about this, you can (depending on your requirements) watermark your images so their origin is obvious, or perhaps display via some custom (Flash?) plugin. Users can obviously take a screenshot, but it makes the process a little less convenient.

Comment: Whatever gets displayed, can get copied. Flash is no pretection, either. Simply take a screenshot and be done with it (the lowest-tech method here).

Comment: Fair point re. the flash. It's a bit more long winded, but yes, you can copy anything that comes up on the screen

Answer (score 1):

If you are worrying about people copying nice photos to use on their own sites, books, whatever, you could show watermarked versions of your photos (like the folks over at [getty](http://www.gettyimages.com/) images), and require a login to retrieve the original (unadulterated) ones. This won't prevent images from being copied, but it will make the copied image less attractive which can be a sufficient deterrent.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments.  I suppose my main idea is to have my friends put there photos and messages in a central place eg. my website, then they can log on and catch up with everyone and see each others photo`s. Sounds familiar I know but I wanted a small group of friends to have one place to catch up with each other and not let the whole world in! So it`s more privacy than copying great photos.

Comment: @Wendy: you can indeed password protect all or part of your Web site.
Note: I believe some, if not all, sites hosting photos (like Flickr, etc.) offer such privacy options, although I never use them.

Answer (score 1):

Password-protecting the site would help. This would keep people who didn't know the password from seeing the photos at all, and then they couldn't copy the pictures. Once they entered the password and had access to the site, though, they could copy the pictures if they liked.

Comment: That sounds good. I just wasn`t sure if once a photo is "out there" it can be found in a search.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using lower resolution images, and as Simon mentioned about an overlay, you may actually want to save the entire image WITH the overlay in some secondary directory.  Anyone who can do VIEW SOURCE of the HTML, find the image name itself directly can get your image all by itself without any secondary visual blur control on top of it.

Comment: Oh how confusing! I need to get my head round this before asking friends to add their photos. Maybe it`s too big an idea for me to complete. Thanks everyone